# output a value from a variable in docker image

Tags: docker

Trying to pass a variable from a `RUN` command to a `CMD` in a docker image. The `v` variable is passed from `value` and contains a number, but it does not output when after the container is run. It is declared as as environmental variable and passed to the `CMD`. Thank you. :).

```
RUN apk add -- \
    && cd directory \
    && value=$(....)

ARG value

ENV value=$value

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo some text $value" ]
```

To run:

```
docker run <image>
```

**current**

```
some text
```

**desired**

```
some text 10
```

Comment: See the part after the Note in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: I updated the post adding an `ARG` to store the `value` on build and then pass that to the `ENV` for so the `$value` is available on run time, but `value` doesn't expand. I updated the `CMD` as well. When I start the container with `-it`, I can run the `value` command and`echo` is contents. Thank you :).